# How to replace a Line break/new line in Google drawtable with PHP

Tags: php, newline, google-calendar-api, line-breaks

The following content breaks my google.visualization.DataTable. I am pulling this from Google calendar.

```
// this one has a line break/enter/new line in google calendar after 5
Kanji lessons from 11 to 15 or Kanji lesson's from 1 to 5 
Beginner students dont have matome quiz. They have usual Katakana quiz from ta to po.
```

But the following works fine.

```
// this does not have it.
Kanji lessons from 11 to 15 or Kanji lesson's from 1 to 5. Beginner students dont have matome quiz. They have usual Katakana quiz from ta to po.
```

I tried the followings. But none of them worked so far.

```
$description = str_replace("&nbsp;&nbsp;"," ",$description);

$description_arr=explode("\\n",$description);

$description = implode("<br />", $description_arr);
```

Whole code

```
// Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['table,corechart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);
// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

// start of tabel
function drawTable() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    //data.addColumn('string', 'Calendar Name');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Date Due');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Summary');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Date Created');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Description');
    data.addRows([
<?php
    if(count($events))
    {
        foreach($events->items as $item)
        {
            //$displayName = str_replace("'", "\'", $item->organizer->displayName);
            $summary = str_replace("'", "\'", $item->getSummary());
            $datedue = str_replace("'", "\'", $item->start->date);
            $description = str_replace("'", "\'", $item->description);
            $description = str_replace("&nbsp;&nbsp;"," ",$description);
            // $description_arr=explode("\\n",$description);
            // $description = implode("<br />", $description_arr);
            echo "['".$datedue."','".$summary . "','" . substr($item->created, 0, 10) ."','".$description."' ],\n";

            //echo "['".$displayName."','".$summary."','".$date . "','" . substr($item->created, 0, 10) ."','".$descrption."' ],\n";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Calendar is private.";
    }
?>

    ]);

    var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
    table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: true, allowHtml:true});
}
// end of table
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the last two lines in the following and it works fine now.

```
$summary = str_replace("'", "\'", $item->getSummary());
$date = str_replace("'", "\'", $item->start->date);
$description = str_replace("'", "\'", $item->description);
// replace line breaks with a space
$description = str_replace("\n"," ",$description);
$description = str_replace("\r"," ",$description);
```